# Reactive Extensions ToEnumerable how to dispose observable state if not iterating everything

Tags: c#, system.reactive, rx.net

If I use the `ToEnumerable` extension on an `IObservable`, there is a chance the user will not iterate all of the elements. In that case how can the `IDisposable` declared in `Observable.Create` be properly disposed?

For the sake of argument let's say that it is not an option to directly return the `IObservable` to the user (in which case the user could implement cancellation themselves).

```
 private IObservable<Object> MakeObservable()
 {
   return Observable.Create(async (observer, cancelToken) =>
   {
     using(SomeDisposable somedisposable = new SomeDisposable())
     {
        while(true)
        {
          Object result = somedisposable.GetNextObject();
          if(result == null)
          {
            break;
          }
          observer.OnNext(result);
        }       
     }
   }
 }

 public IEnumerable<Object> GetObjects()
 {
   return MakeObservable().ToEnumerable();
 }

 public void Test()
 {
   IEnumerable<Object> e = GetObjects();
   int i = 0;
   foreach(Object o in e)
   {
     if(i++ == 10)
        break;
   }
   //somedisposable is not disposed here!!!
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your definition of `Create` doesn't return so it can't be stopped. If you change your source observable to something based on a timer then it works fine. Try this code:

```
public IEnumerable<long> GetObjects()
{
    return Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))
        .Finally(() => Console.WriteLine("Done."))
        .ToEnumerable();
}

public void Test()
{
    foreach (long i in GetObjects())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        if (i == 10)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

When you run that you get this output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
Done.
```

It's clearly calling `OnCompleted` on the source observable.

Comment: Thanks. Although I won't use `Interval`, this answer helped me understand why it's happening. I realized I could make more use of the `cancelToken` which also seems to get cancelled upon exiting the foreach.